# acces JSON from server side

Tags: iphone, json

I have the following response from server:

```
{"_license":false}
```

And when I try to get out from there `_license` it displays `null`.I tried like this:

```
NSString *items = [[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil] valueForKey:@"_license"];
NSLog(@"response server%@", items);
```

Any idea why?And how to solve?

Comment: Confirm that `[request responseString]` contains the string you’re expecting. Check the return value of `-objectWithString:`. If it’s `nil`, check the error output parameter (and pass a valid address instead of `nil`). Also, why aren’t you using `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]`, the canonical method to read dictionary items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try en spilt up your code, don't do every thing in one line. Then check ever variable if it contains the correct value.

```
NSLog(@"Server response: %@",[request responseString]);
NSError * error = nil;

NSDictionary *response = [parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:&error]

if (!response)( {
  NSLog( @"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
  return;
}

NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", response);

NSNumber *hasValidLicense = [response objectForKey:@"_license"];
NSLog(@"Has valid license: %@", hasValidLicense);

if ([hasValidLicense boolValue]){
   //Yes we have a valid license.
} else {
   // No valid license.
}
```

Comment: Note that, in Cocoa Touch error handling, [the error output parameter should only be read if the method return value is `nil` or `NO`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html). One should first check the return value, and then check the error output parameter.

Comment: @Bavarious I've edited my answer. The documentation link is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

replace your line with the following:

```
BOOL items = [[[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil] valueForKey:@"_license"] boolValue];
```

Comment: If the expression before `-boolValue` is `nil`, your answer doesn’t solve the problem. It’ll always assign `NO` to `items`.